# How long should it take to synchronize with blockchain?

Tags: bitcoin-core, synchronization

I expected to find the answer somewhere here, but I could not find it.

I am using windows 10 and the bitcoin core wallet, with 2GB database cache. I have set the wallet to start on system boot, and I boot my system every 1-2 days.

How long should synchronizing with the blockchain take in this case? Let's say I'm 14 hours behind.

For me, Bitcoin core will take about half an hour to sync, and I feel this is way too slow. I have a relatively new gaming laptop with an i7 processor, 8GB RAM. I have Bitcoin core installed on my SSD, and the blockchain is stored on my SSD. I have 40 megabit internet (and I do actually reach similar speeds).

Comment: Any specific reason for using that wallet? There are many light weight wallets that do not require downloading the entire blockchain.

Comment: My original reason was that Bitcoin core is the reference version for older wallets. I am also not sure if light weight wallets are as secure as Bitcoin core?

Comment: Yes there are many secure wallets besides of bitcoin core. Checkout Exodus, Electrum, and even Jaxx. These wallets are light weight, yet you are in control of your funds. :)

Comment: You are seriously suggesting a closed source wallet?   Lightweight wallets are categorically less secure than Bitcoin core and significantly less private. They're faster to start using, but that comes at a cost.

Answer (score 1):

A half hour to sync two days is almost 100x faster than real-time.  It's slower than I would expect, but without more information it's not really possible to tell if there is anything that could be improved about your system or configuration.

Answer (score 0):

When my bitcoin core downloads blockchain on MacBook Air the speed fluctuates from 4MB/s to 12MB/s. So probably 40mbps net speed is limiting you, not a CPU.
Additionally you need time to connect to enough nodes to get full speed.

Answer (score 0):

https://blog.lopp.net/2020-bitcoin-node-performance-tests/

With an SSD the whole thing should be setup within the same day assuming CPU is not too old. Im gonna sync one from scratch myself soon we'll see how long it takes.